# Can Scrapy work on PHP?

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrapy, bookmarklet

Can I use Scrapy on PHP or are there similar tools that work with PHP?

I am not a technical person but just researching the available web scraping tools and their features to support my technical colleagues.

Comment: [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is written in Python... so you could use something like [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) but for a non-technical person - the short answer would be no.

Comment: Are you asking if you can write PHP code to utilise Scrapy or if you can use Scrapy to read websites that are written using PHP?

Answer (score 9):

Scrapy is for python and you can't use that in PHP.

However, in PHP you can use [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to do this job. It uses [Guzzle HTTP](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)  and Symfony components like BrowserKit and [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) behind the scenes to do this job.

Check this out:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

// Go to the symfony.com website
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.symfony.com/blog/');

// Get the latest post in this category and display the titles
$crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    echo $node->text().'\n';
});
```

[More on usage](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte#usage)

PS: Please do note that it doesn't do JavaScript.

Comment: When mentioning Goutte with web scraping one should also mention that it doesn't do JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [PHP SimpleTest's ScriptableBrowser](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html)...

Answer (score 0):

You can't write Scrapy spiders using PHP.

Nevertheless, it's very usual to use Scrapy (writing spiders in Python) and store the extracted data in a database or something accessible by your application. For example, it's fairly easy to store the extracted items directly to ElasticSearch and make your application query ES to search/filter/aggregate the data.

But, if your colleagues don't know Python they will need to spend some time learning the language and then the Scrapy framework.